# Redirect within MapUnknownRoutes in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I want bad routes to navigate to the root route. I've added a `mapUnknownRoutes` configuration on my router.

```
config.mapUnknownRoutes((inst) => inst.config.moduleId = 'home');
```

But this leaves the route untouched. For example, `#/fakeRoute` routes to home. Ideally, I would like a behavior similar to returning `{ redirect: '#/' }`, which cancels navigation and creates a new navigation to the route `'#/'`. Is this a feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `mapUnknownRoutes` method also accepts a [`RouteConfig` object](https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/master/src/interfaces.js) so you can just directly specify your redirect there:

```
config.mapUnknownRoutes({ redirect: '#/' });
```

See the complete signature of the method on [github](https://github.com/aurelia/router/blob/87c0d8cad3efc0bfbe06812f66fa67447e667d2b/src/router-configuration.js#L79-L88)

Comment: This is the right solution functionally, but if you're using typescript, this will not compile. This is because you need to include a dummy `route` property since it is required on the `RouteConfig` interface. Setting mine to `unknown` did the trick: `config.mapUnknownRoutes({ route: 'unknown', redirect: '#/' });`

Comment: This solution does not work for me. The code complains that the parameter must be a string or a function. And for a function, I can't find any working examples where the function is doing a redirect.