# Aurelia : How to handle Unknown routes

Tags: aurelia

I am using below code to handle unknown routes.

```
config.mapUnknownRoutes(instruction =>
{                       
  _self.router.navigate(_self.routerConfigInfo.defaultRoute);           
  return;
});
```

**For example:**

My Default route is "welcome" and  I am currently on Route MyApp which is known route, and now if I change the MYApp to MyApplication(Unknown route) on address bar then my application properly navigate to default route welcome but in the address bar, my URL is still MyApplication. it should show welcome but it's not happening. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Default Route: http://localhost/framework/

Current Route: http://localhost/framework/#/MyApp?cid=123

Changed Route Manually on address bar: http://localhost/framework/#/MyApplication?cid=123

MY URL is http://localhost/framework/#/MyApplication?cid=123 instead of http://localhost/framework/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect within MapUnknownRoutes in Aurelia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33280224/redirect-within-mapunknownroutes-in-aurelia)

Comment: my problem is with the URL, not changing

Comment: The answer in that question is the exact answer you are looking for.